# NextJS Script Tag is not loading when using browser Back and Fwd buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm loading an iframe that needs to load this Script at the same time

```
<Script src="https://embed.acuityscheduling.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

It's loading the iframe's dynamic size I believe.  When I use the browser back and fwd buttons though and land back on that page, it seems like the script is not loading and the Iframe does not look right.

I used Script's onLoad to wait for it to load before rendering the iframe but that doesn't work, so I actually think the iframe needs to load first then the script.

I've tried the different strategies for Script "beforeInteractive" and "afterInteractive" and they don't seem to be doing anything

Any ideas?